# How to repeat ajax call after first call with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to repeat an Ajax Call after first call when checkbox is checked.
The call is success when checkbox is checked but not repeated after that.

Here's my code:

*HTML*

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="data_ref" name="data_ref" value="1">Data Referensi</label>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#data_ref").change(function(event) {
        setInterval(data_ref_h(), 10000);
    });
});

function data_ref_h() {
    var formData = {
        'url': $('input[name=url]').val(),
        'nm_db': $('input[name=nm_db]').val(),
        'user_db': $('input[name=user_db]').val(),
        'port_db': $('input[name=port_db]').val(),
        'pass_db': $('input[name=pass_db]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>cek/cek_ref',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })  

}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Are you seeing any js error or warning messGe in console?

Comment: @Rahul I want repeat the ajax call, but only when checkbox is checked.

Comment: @Shahid no error

Comment: Ok, you can call data_ref_h() again in .done callback if the checkbox is check. No need to add interval.

Comment: I need setinterval because I want the Ajax Call is repeating after 10 Sec when checkbox is checked ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note. This

```
   setInterval(data_ref_h(),10000);
```

will execute call immediately and after that nothing will happens. 
Can you try:

```
   setInterval(data_ref_h,10000);
```